# Python: Getting variable from a function that generates random numbers by pressing a button

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, random

I'm working on a game where you have to roll the dice. When I press the button, a random value from 1 to 6 emerges and is printed in the window - that's fine. The problem is that I need to somehow get the same value as the one that the 'dice' showed. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
 
window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
 
l1=Label(window)
 
def roll():
    dice=random.randint(1,6)
    l1.config(text=f'{dice}')
    l1.pack()
     
b1=Button(window,text="Roll the Dice!",foreground='blue',command=roll)
b1.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

Here I want to get the value *dice* and use this value somewhere else but the function *roll* is bound to the command of the button *b1*. I tried to create another function and even a class but then I run into other problems such as that the number on the dice won't change even after I press the button repeatedly etc. Now I've run out of ideas. Could you edit my code so that the program works just as before but it also returns the value that the *dice* showed so that I can use the same value somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global variable:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window=Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")

l1=Label(window)
l2=Label(window)

def roll():
    global dice
    dice=random.randint(1,6)
    l1.config(text=f'{dice}')
    l1.pack()

def last():
    l2.config(text=f'Last roll was {dice}')
    l2.pack()

b1=Button(window,text="Roll the Dice!",foreground='blue',command=roll)
b1.pack()

b2=Button(window,text="Get last roll",foreground='blue',command=last)
b2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

NOTE: This requires you to push the "roll" button first. If you push the "last" button  first, you get a `NameError` exception (which can be prevented by defining `dice` with an initial value in the global scope).

Comment: Thank you, however I'd like to have the last roll on the dice stored as a variable because I need to move a figure in the game onto another field and this depends on the number that the dice generated. That's why I need to somehow get the value on the dice alone and not print out the number in the window. Nonetheless, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Uhm, you can access ``dice`` anywhere in your module after it is set once, not just for printing. It is stored as the **global** variable ``dice``. The printing with the second button was just to show that ``dice`` is also available in the function ``last``.

Comment: I think that I've managed to figure out what the problem was - I wanted to use `dice` before it was even defined. Thanks for the help!